# Error with Python 3 in RPi

Tags: python-3.4, raspberry-pi2, gpio, led, gamepad

First, sorry if I have a bad English or if anything is wrong, this is my first "post".
I'm trying to use a USB gamepad to turn an LED on and off with `gpiozero`.
I have an error while trying to execute the program:

```
import sys
from gpiozero import LED
led = LED(17)
pipe = open('/dev/input/js0', 'rb')
msg = []
while 1:
    for char in pipe.read(1):
        msg += [ord(char)]
            if len(msg) == 8:
                if msg[6] == 1:
                    if msg[4] == 1:
                        print ('button', msg[7], 'down')
                        led.on()
                    else:
                        print ('button', msg[7], 'up')
                        led.off()
                msg = []
```

> Error:
>       File "script.py", line 13, in <module>
>         msg += [ord(char)]
>       TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

What can I do to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please, add both the code and the error message as "text".

Comment: It's done, hope you can help.

Comment: can u post the error u are getting ?

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot it.

Comment: I really need this help please i hope you can help me

Comment: `char` is already an integer, you don't have to convert a bytestring to int here. Just drop `ord()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't get it to work with the version I was using, I just used a different python version instead.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like to are trying to add items to a list. Make use of append().

Documentation:
list.append(x)
Add an item to the end of the list. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].

Example of append vs extend for future use:
[append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend)